# Using switch function in R I want to give a conditional result based on an empty row

Tags: r, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements

For example

```
df$Col2 <- sapply(df$Col1, switch,
"001"= "Gold",
"005" = "Silver", 
"007" = "Platinum",
""= "OTHER)
```

Up to "007" it works, but when I add the last empty row in the condition i then get an error message saying

```
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

Is there a way to have it read the empty cell and based on that give it the conditional value i ask of it?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(Col2 = case_when(Col1 == '001' ~ 'Gold',
        Col1 == '005' ~ "Silver",
        Col1 == '007' ~ 'Platinum', 
         TRUE ~ "OTHER"))
```

---

WIth `switch`, we can have `default` option as the last entry

```
df$Col2 <- sapply(df$Col1, switch,
     "001"= "Gold",
     "005" = "Silver", 
     "007" = "Platinum", "OTHER")
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized removing ""= was enough to get it to do what i wanted.

```
df$Col2 <- sapply(df$Col1, switch,
"001"= "Gold",
"005" = "Silver", 
"007" = "Platinum",
"OTHER")
```